# What should we do about link rot to popular sites?

Tags: discussion

As pointed out [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50900731#50900731), we have 295 links pointing to Glen Fiddler's site, which is no longer up. Based on the Pateron he had to support that work, it seems [he is no longer working on that content](https://www.patreon.com/gafferongames). There was some further conversation in chat about what might be done to improve this situation and I thought it might be worth having a more formal discussion about the matter here.

What should we do about link rot to popular sites? Note: I'm not asking about general link rot & one-off problems, but situations like links to Glen Fiddler's site where there is a relatively large number of links.

Also, I'm aware of the general policy that good posts should work without links. I agree with that thinking. Rather, I'm interested in discussion about situations where many posts could possibly be restored to their original level of usefulness by addressing link rot to a given resource.